# .NET Core and Windows 2012R2 vs Windows 2016

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

We are currently running .NET Core on Windows 2012R2. How do you feel running it on 2012R2 vs 2016? Will support of 2012R2 vanish anytime soon? Any new capabilities in 2016 (in addition to container support), any performance improvements with 2016 and IIS 10?

Thanks!